# Ubuntu 12.04.5 - unable to connect to internet

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I have just installed ubuntu 12.04.5-desktop-i386

However, i am unable to connect to the internet. Also, do i have to download packages?
Any other info needed? Please do ask.

Thanks!

Comment: In which network ubuntu is connected directly to ISP or In a LAN, and test your NIC by type ping 127.0.0.1

Comment: It is connected to the LAN. Will test a ping to 127.0.0.1 and let you know.

Comment: Was internet access present during the installation process? Did click the check-box for "install 3rd party software" when installing Ubuntu?

Comment: You can use "sudo lshw -C network" to find out what ethernet controller you have. It would be useful to add the product details to your post.